# rails autocomplete path on form edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario wherein I create a payer.I use autocomplete-jquery gem for the payer name.

Now I need to edit the same.This is the path I used in both the places
"autocomplete_payer_name".

For new payer autocomplete is working but not for edit.since 18/autocomplete_payer_name no route found.

How do I specify the autocomplete path for edit

Please help.

Comment: I need to see your code..

Comment: well I could fix this by modifying the path in my routes to         match '/admin/excluded_payer/(:id)/autocomplete_payer_name',:to => 'admin/excluded_payer#autocomplete_payer_name'

Comment: I have got a similar issue. If you found the answer can you please post it here? thnx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I could fix this by modifying the path in my routes to match

'/admin/excluded_payer/(:id)/autocomplete_payer_name',:to => 'admin/excluded_payer#autocomplete_payer_name'

On clicking edit i had a id along with the normal autocomplete call , I just routed it back to the normal one assuming it didn't have the id.

I got this issue while on record edit.